# Use an image for a header border bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to use an image for the bottom border of an image. The image used for the border bottom is 400px for example, however I don't want it to display a 400px bottom border for headings the are only short, I want it to auto-scale.

Is there a way to display only the amount required for individual headings rather than having to make up lots of image sizes for multiple heading widths.

Thank you for any help in advance...

Comment: will the border be a static height? can you just use a single pixel width and repeat it across the bottom?

Comment: Not quite understanding the question, you only provide one dimension for your picture and you worded it quite confusingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS3 `border-image` property.

For instance

```
DIV {
  border: double orange 1em;
  border-image: url("border.png") 27 round stretch;
 }
```

You can `stretch` or `repeat` as necessary.

Read more here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images

If looks as if you could also `slice` the image

And more here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-image-slice

Comment: @user699872 - if you provided the image (preferably) and/or the code you have so far, we can fiddle with it.